# WordPress migration to windows server causes redirect loop on home page

Tags: wordpress, loops, redirect, migration

I just migrated my wordpress website to a 2008 Windows server running IIS 7

The migration worked fine and all pages showing fine except that the homepage is causing an infinite redirect loop.

here is the homepage (where the redirect loop is): [this is not a link](http://www.aalphayellowcab.net)

The [this is not a link](http://www.aalphayellowcab.net/about) page works fine:

I have tried the following but to no avail:

1) I have re-saved my permalinks on the wordpress, this did not help.

2) On the wp-config.php file I have added:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.aalphayellowcab.net');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.aalphayellowcab.net');
```

I have also added:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
/** define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', ''); **/
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

3) I then added this rule to the web.config file (Windows does not use the .htaccess file):

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true"> 
   <match url=".*" /> 
   <conditions> 
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^aalphayellowcab.net$" /> 
         </conditions> 
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.aalphayellowcab.net/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
</rule>
```

Nothing seems to work, is there something I can do to over write the loop? What can I do to resolve this issue? I am thinking maybe there is another php file that is causing this.

Thanks in advance,

Louis

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer under this link:

http://artofsimplicity.co.uk/wordpress-3-1-infinite-redirect-after-upgrade-on-windows-server/

Basically, I removed a snippet that was in the functions.php file under 
/wp-content/themes/mysite/functions.php

It's the first snippet on the file.

I hope this helps someone else.